# Retrieving and displaying data from MySql in PhP

Tags: php, mysql

I have ran into a problem that says:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string in F:\University\xampp\htdocs\database.php on line 36

Connection to a database is successful it is just that I cannot retrieve a data from my database and display it on the page.

Here's my database:

http://screenshot.sh/m1Ol9a8Fp2j3a

And here is my code

```
    <?php
$conn = new PDO(
    'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=u1358595', 
    'root'
    );
try{
       $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=u1358595', 'root');
    echo "Connected successfully"; 
}

catch (PDOException $exception) 
{
    echo "Oh no, there was a problem" . $exception->getMessage();
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM hotel";
$results = $conn->query($query, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$hotel = $results->fetch();
echo "<p>".$results."</p>";
$conn=NULL;
?>
```

Comment: Move the  PDO::FETCH_OBJ to fetch `$hotel = $results->fetch( PDO::FETCH_OBJ);`

Comment: still gives me that error message ;/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to echo a PDO Object which doesn't work. You are passing the data to `$hotel` and to show the data you will use hotel.

```
<?php
$conn = new PDO(
    'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=u1358595', 
    'root'
    );
try{
       $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=u1358595', 'root');
    echo "Connected successfully"; 
}

catch (PDOException $exception) 
{
    echo "Oh no, there was a problem" . $exception->getMessage();
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM hotel";
$results = $conn->query($query);
$hotel = $results->fetch();

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($hotel);
echo '</pre>';

$conn=NULL;
?>
```

Comment: Thank you that works, how about if I want to get rid of this and only show the actual information from the table/                                        array(16) {
  ["hotel_id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["name"]=>
  string(11) "The Midland"
  [1]=>
  string(11) "The Midland"
  ["address"]=>
  string(11) "16 Peter St"
  [2]=>
  string(11) "16 Peter St"
  ["postcode"]=>
  string(7) "M60 2DS"
  [3]=>
  string(7) "M60 2DS"
  ["town"]=>
  string(10) "Manchester"
  [4]=>
  string(10) "Manchester"
  ["description"]=>

Comment: You can display individual items from the array like `echo $hotel['name'];` and `echo $hotel['address'];`

Comment: So I want the information from the table only, not the column names etc:http://screenshot.sh/m2d6HUP3VBTpi